# Binding HTTP body into request object in ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Given I have `AppointmentRequest` class

```
public class AppointmentRequest
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset EndTime { get; set; }

}
```

I also have this controller endpoint which maps HTTP body to `AppointmentRequest`

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public async Task<ActionResult<AppointmentResponse>> CreateAppointmentAsync(
    [FromBody] AppointmentRequest appointmentRequest,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
}
```

How can I figure out what component handles this binding and what formatters are in play?

How do I know what date time format is in use?

Comment: `How can I figure out what component handles this binding and what formatters are in play?`.It will use built-in model binder.If you want to know what formatters are in play,you can create a middleware and check content-type in request.